# Não redirecionar formulário - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Eu tenho um formulário onde mando requisições POST pro nodejs salvar no banco de dados mas quando eu envio as informações ele é redirecionado pra rota e eu recebo o res

```
{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":1,"insertId":7,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
```

Só que eu preciso que ele continue na página do formulário e só envie um alerta pro usuário dizendo que  foi cadastrado com sucesso, como eu faço isso?

```
  router.post("/reportar", (req, res) => {
    const latitude = req.body.latitude.substring(0, 10);
    const longitude = req.body.longitude.substring(0, 11);
    const descricao = req.body.longitude.substring(0, 700);
     execSQLQuery(
      `INSERT INTO erros (latitude, longitude, descricao) VALUES ('${latitude}','${longitude}','${descricao}')`,res);
  });
```

```
<form id="contacts" autocorrect="off" name="adicionar" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="http://192.168.0.30:3000/reportar">

<input id="valorlat" type="text" name="latitude" value="">
<input id="valorlong" type="text" name="longitude" value="">
<textarea class="input-field" class="textarea1" name="descricao">
<button type="submit"> Enviar </button>

</form>
```

```
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://192.168.0.30:3000/reportar",
    success: function(response){
      alert("Banheiro adicionado com sucesso")
    }
});
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa, eu não entendi muito bem. Você tem um form HTML e um botão submit?

Comment: isso, só que quando eu clico no submit ele entra nessa tela, e eu queria que ele ficasse na tela do formulário

Comment: Você poderia por favor colocar a parte do código referente ao HTML do form e o método que é chamado ao submeter o form?

Comment: Basicamente, basta indicar para que o comportamento padrão não seja executado, mas para explicar melhor eu preciso saber como está a estrutura do seu form.

Comment: atualizei com o meu formulário. Ele envia e faz tudo certo, só que em vez de ele redirecionar pra pagina que mostra aquela primeira linha de código, eu quero que ele fique na página do formulário mas de um alerta ao usuário de que foi cadastrado com sucesso ou que houve um problema na hora de cadastrar, mas sem redirecionar pra outra página

Answer (score -1):

Você pode especificar um método para ser executado ao submeter o form

```
<form
   id="contacts"
   autocorrect="off"
   name="adicionar"
   onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction(event);" >
```

E na implementação do método você previne o comportamento padrão de redirecionamento e faz a requisição, manipula a resposta, etc.

```
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // aqui você faz a requisição

  // faz o alert

  return false;
}
```

Comment: não consegui, como ficaria a requisição?

Comment: editei lá como eu fiz

Answer (score -3):

Não sei como está o código mas poderia tentar tirar a action da tag  e fazer uma requisição ajax dentro da sua mySubmitFunction. Obs.: Mantenha o preventDefault

Comment: atualizei lá, mas não funcionou, tem como ver o que eu to fazendo de errado?